# Special indexes in durable memory

Tags: ignite

1. I want to make special indexes (lucene indexes) in my program. I wrote my
   custom IndexingSpi, but I do not know how to better implement queries for
   these custom indexes through a standard ignite interface (I'm thinking of
   doing something like views for table).
2. Is it possible to store the created custom lucene indexes in Ignite's
   Durable Memory? How Ignite indexes (lucene) store for Durable Memory?

Comment: Show what you did till now and what is the question to the first point?

Comment: I think that's a highly non-trivial task. Ignite doesn't even persist its own Lucene indexes yet. I recommend wrapping your code together and writing to ignite developer list.
Other than that, look how TextQuery is implemented.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Is there a reason why built-in text queries do not work? https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-queries#text-queries

Comment: I need calculate groups and facets, present the data in the hierarchies or pivotal tables. Indexes (lucene index) allow you to quickly calculate the result and select only the resulting records from the key-values store. The IndexingSpi solves my task, but two issues are not solved. 1. IndexingSpi can return a response only Iterator<Cache.Entry<*, *>> (Key, BinaryObject). I would like additional data in the returned data (MyResponse<Iterator<Cache.Entry<*, *>>>, when MyResponse<...> include myAdditionalData: BinaryObject).
2. I would like to store indexes (lucene index) in durable memory.

Comment: @user9532707 Perhaps instead of indexing SPI, you should look at deploying an Ignite service. This way you will be able implement it using all Ignite public APIs, including cache and compute, and therefore, utilize durable memory as much as needed. Here is more info on Ignite service grid: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/service-grid